# How to keep keep original column after applying data validation in same column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a task to validate decimal and date field.I am able to validate decimal and date filed on same column but not able to keep old column values.

Input:

```
id,amt1
1,123
2,321
3,345
4,543
5,789
```

Current Output:

```
id,amt1
1,12.3
2,32.1
3,34.5
4,54.3
5,78.9
```

Expected Output:

```
id,amt1,original_amt1_values
1,12.3,123
2,32.1,321
3,34.5,345
4,54.3,543
5,78.9,789
```

Below is the code, I am able to validate decimal filed but not able to keep original values. Kindly help me on this. I want to keep its original column in dataframe itself.

```
 SourceFileDF = SourceFileDF.withColumn("amt1", DecimalConversion(col(amt1)))
```

DecimalConversion is my UDF and SourceFileDF  is my dataframe.

Comment: The problem is that you overwrite the input column `amt1` with the new, converted column. Either change the name of the input column before adding the new one, or use another name for the new column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a temporary column name for "amt1" and the use column rename

```
SourceFileDF.withColumn("amt1_converted", DecimalConversion(col(amt1)))
SourceFileDF.withColumnRenamed("amt1", "original_amt1_values")
SourceFileDF.withColumnRenamed("amt1_converted", "amt1")
```

Comment: its changing the column positions. Like validated columns appending at last.I want validated column on old place and original value on last position.There are are around 100 columns and process is automated

Comment: solution is working as expected only column position changes.

Comment: as per your solution out put position is :- id,original_amt1_values,amt1 but I want id,amt1,original_amt1_values

Comment: Please edit your question, you haven't mention anything related to the number of columns and position changes

Answer (score 0):

You can use select and provide the alias in a single line :

```
sourceFileDF.select( 
     DecimalConversion($"amt1").as("amt1") , 
     $"amt1".as("original_amt1_values") 
)
```

Comment: its suitable for one columns but I have multiple columns.for this I am able to retrieve only "amt1" column and "original_amt1_values" not able to select others column. I Have 100 columns in my file out of some are decimal and some are date and so on columns.